# MySQL UNION query is taking time

Tags: mysql

In below query there are three UNIONs. each union is taking 4 seconds to execute and total query execution time is 12 seconds. is there any way to fine tune or re write this query? Each union has different columns in where clause, so adding more index also not good choice.

```
Select distinct el.ProblemID,el.SLAID,et.Esca_level  from escalation_lookup el, sd_servicereqmaster s,escalation_timeslots et, escalation_details ed where s.ProblemID = el.ProblemID and el.IsEsca1_Breached = 0 and el.SLAID = et.SLA_ID and et.Esca_level = 1 and ed.SLA_ID = et.SLA_ID and ed.SLA_ID = el.SLAID and ed.IsSLARuleActive = 1 and Estimated_Esca1_BreachTime <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and Interval_time=1 and NBD_cutoff_time=0
               and ((el.TotalTimeConsider > et.EscaTime_Min and el.IsTicketActive = 0) OR (el.TotalTimeConsider > et.EscaTime_Min and el.Previous_Status = 0 and el.IsTicketActive = 1) OR (el.Previous_Status = 1 and el.IsTicketActive = 1 and Estimated_Esca1_BreachTime < now()))
 union all

    Select distinct el.ProblemID,el.SLAID,et.Esca_level  from escalation_lookup el, sd_servicereqmaster s,escalation_timeslots et, escalation_details ed where s.ProblemID = el.ProblemID and el.IsEsca2_Breached = 0 and el.SLAID = et.SLA_ID  and et.Esca_level = 2 and ed.SLA_ID = et.SLA_ID and ed.SLA_ID = el.SLAID and ed.IsSLARuleActive = 1 and Estimated_Esca2_BreachTime <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and Interval_time=1 and NBD_cutoff_time=0
               and ((el.TotalTimeConsider > et.EscaTime_Min and el.IsTicketActive = 0) OR (el.TotalTimeConsider > et.EscaTime_Min and el.Previous_Status = 0 and el.IsTicketActive = 1) OR (el.Previous_Status = 1 and el.IsTicketActive = 1 and Estimated_Esca2_BreachTime < now()))
    union all
Select distinct el.ProblemID,el.SLAID,et.Esca_level  from escalation_lookup el, sd_servicereqmaster s,escalation_timeslots et, escalation_details ed where s.ProblemID = el.ProblemID and el.IsEsca3_Breached = 0 and el.SLAID = et.SLA_ID and et.Esca_level = 3 and ed.SLA_ID = et.SLA_ID and ed.SLA_ID = el.SLAID and ed.IsSLARuleActive = 1 and Estimated_Esca3_BreachTime <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and Interval_time=1 and NBD_cutoff_time=0
               and ((el.TotalTimeConsider > et.EscaTime_Min and el.IsTicketActive = 0) OR (el.TotalTimeConsider > et.EscaTime_Min and el.Previous_Status = 0 and el.IsTicketActive = 1) OR (el.Previous_Status = 1 and el.IsTicketActive = 1 and Estimated_Esca3_BreachTime < now()))
```

different column used in each union are

```
UNION 1
IsEsca1_Breached
Esca_level =1
Estimated_Esca1_BreachTime

UNION 2
IsEsca2_Breached
Esca_level =2
Estimated_Esca2_BreachTime

UNION 3
IsEsca3_Breached
Esca_level =3
Estimated_Esca3_BreachTime
```

table1,
CREATE TABLE `escalation_lookup` (
`SiteID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`slno` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`SlaID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ProblemID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Esca_1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Esca_2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`EmailEsca_1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`EmailEsca_2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`SLA_BreachTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Esca1_BreachTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Esca1_SendTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Esca2_BreachTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Esca2_SendTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`LastCalculatedTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`Previous_Status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
`TotalTimeConsider` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`IsTicketActive` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
`TicketGenStatus` varchar(8) DEFAULT '00',
`Estimated_SLABreachTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Estimated_Esca1_BreachTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Estimated_Esca2_BreachTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Estimated_GracePeriod_BreachTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`IsSLA_Breached` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
`IsEsca1_Breached` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
`IsEsca2_Breached` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
`IsActualResolutionTimeConsider` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
`Esca_3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`EmailEsca_3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Esca3_BreachTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Esca3_SendTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Estimated_Esca3_BreachTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`IsEsca3_Breached` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`slno`),
KEY `Problem_ID` (`ProblemID`),
KEY `SLAStatus_ProblemID` (`ProblemID`,`IsSLA_Breached`),
KEY `Combined_key` (`ProblemID`,`IsEsca1_Breached`,`IsEsca2_Breached`,`SlaID`),
KEY `Estimated_SLABreachTime` (`Estimated_SLABreachTime`),
KEY `probleimid_slaid` (`ProblemID`,`SlaID`),
KEY `TotalTimeConsider` (`TotalTimeConsider`),
KEY `slaid` (`SlaID`),
KEY `slaid_problemid` (`SlaID`,`ProblemID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7755116 DEFAULt utf8.

table 2
CREATE TABLE `sd_servicereqmaster` (
`ProblemId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Title` varchar(2048) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`SubmittedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Owner` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`CurrentStatus` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Category` int(11) NOT NULL,
`SubCategory` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Platform` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Severity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`CreationTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`ProbDescription` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`CcMailId` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
`AlternativeEmail` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
`ContactNumber` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
`Attachment` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Enclosure` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ApprovalManager` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`LocationID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`DepartmentID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`Resolution_CauseID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Resolution_Days` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Resolution_Hours` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Resolution_Minutes` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`SubmittedThrough` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`AlertID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`LastOperatedTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`GroupID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RepeatCall` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ResolutionComment` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
`REQUESTTYPE` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`AssetNumber` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`SLAViolationComment` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`ParentID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ConversionType` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`DerivedField1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`DerivedField2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`DerivedField3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RequestID` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
`ProjectID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`ServiceID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`IsTransferred` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ReferenceID` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`LevelOneStatus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`LevelTwoStatus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ProxySubmittedBy` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`DelegatedFrom_Owner` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`DelegatedFrom_ApprovalManager` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`UrgencyID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ImpactID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`isLinked` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`CSI` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`IncidentType` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ExpectedClosureTime` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`ProjectTransferComment` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
`IsRead` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`IsRead_UserID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`SchedulerecordType` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`VERSION` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ProblemId`),
KEY `Owner_SubmittedBy` (`SubmittedBy`,`Owner`),
KEY `Current_Status` (`CurrentStatus`),
KEY `Sub_Category` (`SubCategory`),
KEY `Creation_Time` (`CreationTime`),
KEY `FK_sd_servicereqmaster_1` (`ProjectID`),
KEY `FK_sd_servicereqmaster_2` (`ServiceID`),
KEY `FK_sd_servicereqmaster_3` (`Category`),
KEY `index_LocationID` (`LocationID`),
KEY `index_DepartmentID` (`DepartmentID`),
KEY `index_ImpactID` (`ImpactID`),
KEY `index_UrgencyID` (`UrgencyID`),
KEY `index_Priority` (`Priority`),
KEY `index_GroupID` (`GroupID`),
KEY `index_SubmittedThrough` (`SubmittedThrough`),
KEY `index_ApprovalManager` (`ApprovalManager`),
KEY `index_DerivedField1` (`DerivedField1`),
KEY `index_DerivedField2` (`DerivedField2`),
KEY `index_DerivedField3` (`DerivedField3`),
KEY `index_RequestID` (`RequestID`(255)),
KEY `ParentID` (`ParentID`),
KEY `owner` (`Owner`),
KEY `isLinked` (`isLinked`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_sd_servicereqmaster_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectID`) REFERENCES `sd_project_master` (`ProjectID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_sd_servicereqmaster_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ServiceID`) REFERENCES `sd_service` (`ServiceID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

table 3
CREATE TABLE `escalation_details` (
`SiteID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`SLA_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Name` varchar(256) DEFAULT '',
`Formula` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
`Rule` varchar(4096) DEFAULT '',
`ResolveTime` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
`ResolveTime_Min` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`GraceTime` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0 Day(s) 0 Hour(s) 0 Mins',
`GraceTime_Min` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
`TicketGenID` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`IsSLARuleActive` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
`BusinessHrs_Profile` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`Holidays_Profile` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`ProjectID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`IsResponseRequired` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1-Enable Alert Message, 0-Disable Alert Message',
`Interval_time` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`NBD_cutoff_time` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`NBD_without_cutofftime_Businessday` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`NBD_With_Cutofftime` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
`NBD_With_before_cutofftime_Businessday` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`NBD_With_After_cutofftime_Businessday` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Additionalfieldid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`SLA_ID`),
KEY `FK_escalation_details_1` (`ProjectID`),
KEY `NBD_cutoff_time` (`NBD_cutoff_time`),
KEY `sla_id` (`SLA_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_escalation_details_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectID`) REFERENCES `sd_project_master` (`ProjectID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ;

Comment: I doubt anyone can help you if you don't provide more details about your query and database.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the fields in the tables?

Comment: I have added the table details , I am unable to add query execution plan as attaching email is not allowed now.